# Inserting XYZ axis in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have a 3D line layer which I have made to a layout and tilted. I want to show how the view coresponds to XYZ and insert a XYZ axis.

Where can I find this in Pro?

Now it just shows overlapping lines. I'm using 2.2.

[image: Here is something like the one I want. It can also be with three arrows.]